# NSLayoutConstraint is not being removed

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add a constraint programmatically to selected UITextField inside UITableViewCell. It is added successfully and selected text field width is being increased.
But when I try to remove the added constraint then it doesn't work. Can Any one figure out where Am I doing the mistake?

```
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    if (self.currentTextField.tag!=HEADER_FIELD_TAG) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.currentTextField];
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraintTrail = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.currentTextField.superview
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.currentTextField
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:0.0];

        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        CGRect tableRect = self.currentTextField.frame;
        if (movedUp)
        {
            // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
            // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
            [self.currentTextField.superview addConstraint:constraintTrail];
            rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
            rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
            tableRect.size.width += 800;

        }
        else
        {
            // revert back to the normal state.
            [self.currentTextField.superview removeConstraints:@[constraintTrail]];
            rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
            rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
            tableRect.size.width -= 800;
        }
        infoFieldTable.frame = tableRect;
        self.view.frame = rect;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it's obviously not working.

If I imagine right, `setViewMovedUp` is a setter, executed when the `viewMovedUp` property changes.

When the method is executed, you create a new constraint with:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraintTrail = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.currentTextField.superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.currentTextField
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0];
```

Based on the value of `movedUp` you either add it or try to remove it. So if you set `viewMovedUp` to `YES` 5 times in a row, you'll have 5 constraints. When you set it to `NO`, you're trying to remove a newly created constraint, not the one which was previously added.

---

What you most likely want is to create a property for that constraint:

```
@property (nonatonic, strong) NSLayoutContraint *constraintTrail;
```

and change your code to:

```
    if (!self.contraintTrail) {
        self.contraintTail = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.currentTextField.superview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.currentTextField
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0];
    }
```

This way, you only create on `NSLayoutContraint` instance, and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add the constraint only once (maybe in the setup method or event the `storyboard` and have an `IBOutlet` to it) and then active/deactivate it according to your logic.

```
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    if (self.currentTextField.tag!=HEADER_FIELD_TAG) {

        // All your logic here ...

        // Set the active property on the constraint
        [self.constraintTrail setActive:movedUp];
    }
}
```

Another point would be that you are not calling `layoutIfNeeded`after you change the constraints. This method causes the view to relayout it's subviews with the new constraints.

Hope it works! Let me know how it goes though :)